# How to parse page with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am writing a parser and  found that I can't parse http://ekaterinburg.irr.ru/equipment/trade/showcase/.

I have code:

```
link = "http://ekaterinburg.irr.ru/equipment/trade/showcase/"
page = open(link, :allow_redirections => :all)
page  = Nokogiri::HTML page
@result = page.to_html
```

But if I print `@result` in my Rails console using Byebug I get only this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n\n
```

If I try something like `page.css('title')` it won't find anything too.

This code works fine for another pages.

If it is relevant I also use

```
gem 'addressable'
gem 'open_uri_redirections'
```

When I write `Nokogiri::HTML page` I get something about `not_used_cookie` message:

```
(byebug) Nokogiri::HTML page
#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x..fd980c3da name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x..fd980c20e name="html">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fda73e682 name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fda73e4d4 name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fda73e33a name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fda73e10a "{\"message\":\"not_used_cookie\"}">]>]>]>]>
```

I did some more searching and found this page on the site I parse:

http://irr.ru/ajax/2012/common/action/passport_answer.php?message=login_fail&redirect=/&er=2

It also has a message `not_used_cookie`.

Comment: Why are you using backticks? That code will raise an exception.

Comment: @matt I actually use double backticks `" "` (don't know how they are called in english). Consider this as a misprint.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We need to see the minimal HTML necessary to duplicate the problem in your question itself. Links rot then break and when they do your question won't make sense to anyone looking at it in the future. We also need to be able to run the stripped code to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) instead of OpenURI.

The site expects cookies to be set:

```
page = open(link)
page.read
 => "{\"message\":\"not_used_cookie\"}"
```

Mechanize automatically stores and sends cookies, follows redirects, and can follow links and submit forms.